# How can I test DB2 9.5 -> 9.7 Migration/Upgrade?

Tags: database, migration, db2, upgrade

I am going to migrate a DB2 9.5 database into DB2 9.7. I hope that it will be a smooth process. But I want to be sure that the applications are not affected in a negative manner.

"you can run your application and see if everything works" would be a way to ensure the database functionality needed. 
What I want to know is

- Is there any subject/DB2 functionality that I need to pay particular attention to.
- What is the best testing way that I can choose.
- Is there a functionality that improves the performance that i must add to my old DB Structure.

Any help will be welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has a very nice upgrade guide that covers those topics (and more!) on the [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/c0023662.html).  I highly recommend you check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture replay tool named iReplay to capture your db traffic and test it against DB2 9.7. http://exact-solutions.com/products/iReplay

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with this product?

Comment: Yes, I am a VP at Exact Solutions, which created the product.

Comment: Gotcha... Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.